# How to "merge" multiple results in one query? (Or sum up)

Tags: mysql

currently my table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `taxes` (
`id` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
);
```

If I want to sum up all the taxes in one month I use:

```
SELECT SUM(`amount`) as `taxesThisMonth` FROM `taxes` WHERE `time` > '2014-10-01 00:00:00'
```

this works fine. But is it possible to sum up all taxes per name? The Name entry could be in the database mutiple times like:

```
INSERT INTO `taxes` (`id`, `time`, `name`, `amount`) VALUES
(1, '2014-10-29 08:59:51', 'Lukas M', '637687.80'),
(2, '2014-10-29 07:39:50', 'Lukas M.', '430500.15'),
(3, '2014-10-29 07:14:50', 'Simon F.', '511707.00'),
(4, '2014-10-29 06:49:49', 'Alex B.', '140982.30');
```

So that I get a result that has 3 rows and Lukas M. is "merged" into one result?

Thanks a lot for you help! I didn't use MySQL for a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `group by` to sum up data per group, so the query becomes

```
SELECT
name,
SUM(`amount`) as `taxesThisMonth` 
FROM `taxes` 
WHERE `time` > '2014-10-01 00:00:00'
group by name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group by the name:

```
SELECT name,SUM(`amount`) as `taxesThisMonth` 
FROM `taxes` 
WHERE `time` > '2014-10-01 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the name field and a GROUP BY Clause

```
SELECT SUM(`amount`) as `taxesThisMonth`, 'name' FROM `taxes` WHERE `time` > '2014-10-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY 'name'
```